# How to configure web api's json serializer to convert date time into ISO 8601 format?

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-web-api, datetime-format, jsonserializer

I am working on web api project and inside my **WebApiConfig** class I have added this configuration to convert datetime parameters into ISO 8601 format:

```
  IsoDateTimeConverter converter = new IsoDateTimeConverter
        {
            //DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal,
            DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'"
        };

     config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(converter);
```

But if I pass in this value **2018-01-21T21:00:00.000Z** from front-end side it does not convert it correctly into **2018-01-22 00:00:00.000**

So, what's wrong with my configurations?

Comment: Why would it convert into that date? You pass in a DateTime string with a timezone (zulu, aka UTC).

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to use `IsoDateTimeConverter` just do:

```
var strDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-01-21T21:00:00.000Z").ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

it will give you `2018-01-22T00:30:00.000Z` as I tested as your string format.

but you can change the format ;ike `"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss"`

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I want to configure json serializer globally